# Can I create C++ and Java projects within the same version of eclipse?

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse, ide

I learnt to program using Java in eclipse. Recently I've wanted to learn C and C++ so I installed the C/C++ version of eclipse. I still have some Java programming to do though and the option to create a new Java project has disappeared.

Is there an easy way to have both C++ and Java projects accessible on eclipse or should I find a new IDE to code Java in? If I was to reinstall the Java version of eclipse would it remove the C++ version?

Comment: ofcourse you can do it, just need download the correct plugins.

Comment: Just write a C++ IDE with Eclipse using Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse is a platform, you can most certainly use it for C/C++ and Java at the same time. The development tools for each language are actually just plugins. That said, many people prefer to use separate installations for each language, so as to keep their workspaces clean.

If you want to install the Java tools in your C/C++ IDE you can go to `Help > Install New Software...`, and search for "Java Development Tools."